# Alternating sum of the reciprocals of the twin primes $\sum(\frac1p-\frac1{p+2})$

Tags: sequences-and-series, number-theory, prime-numbers, twin-primes, sieve-theory

I ask if the limit of the alternating sum of the reciprocals of the twin primes
$$\sum_{p,\,p+2\,\in\,P}\Big(\frac1p-\frac1{p+2}\Big)=\frac13-\frac15+\frac15-\frac17+\frac1{11}-\frac1{13}\;+\;...=0.2159679498...$$
has been ever named in any way, similarly to Brun's constant.

Many thanks.

Comment: Since $1/p-1/(p+2)=2/p(p+2)$ indicates that the series definitely converges, so it's much less significant than Brun's constant.

Comment: In fact, an alternating series already converges if the absolute values of the summands strictly decrease and tend to $0$. This is obviously the case here. But the mentioned hint is also excellent.

Comment: Should there be only finite many twin primes, the alternating sum is finite, so converging as well.